# MPI vs Charm++ : Difference

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, distributed, charm++

I am new to both MPI and charm++. They both seem to do same work, but researchers prefer charm++ over MPI (not sure about this fact, concluded this based on a quick view of some papers in distributed systems). Can anyone please provide me with difference between these two?

Comment: Given the overwhelming amount of MPI applications and the handful of Charm++ ones, I have no idea how you've managed to reach the conclusion that researches prefer the latter. Besides both do **not** do the same work - MPI is a pretty low-level message-passing API while Charm++ is an object-oriented distributed programming paradigm that _may_ use MPI for its own messaging needs.

Comment: This is a pretty huge question. You should probably narrow it down by specifying something in particular that you are trying to figure out. The scope of everything covered by MPI and Charm++ is much bigger that will work in an answer here.

Comment: I want to stimulate a distributed producer-consumer problem, and need to assert some properties of the system on their completion.